# Displaying rows with given id (SELECT WHERE statement) in SQLite doesnt work Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

I have this method in my `SqliteOpenHelper` class:

```
public String getTablica(int id,Context context)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

    String query="SELECT "+COL2+" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+COL1+"="+id;

    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);

   try {
       cursor.moveToFirst();

       return cursor.getString(1);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       Toast.makeText(context,ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       return "";
   }
}
```

I'm getting this error on line cursor.getString(1)

[image]

I would like to print only first row that has id matching the id from function parameter... But im getting this error, how to solve it and what Im doing wrong?

Comment: Just a tip about your code. If you are only reading data from your database you should use `getReadableDatabase()` instead of `getWritableDatabase()`.  Generally, it won't make a big difference...until it suddenly does make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString(int)):

> getString (int columnIndex)
>   Returns the value of the requested column as a String.
>
> The result and whether this method throws an exception when the column value is null or the column type is not a string type is implementation-defined.
>
> Parameters
>
> columnIndex
>   int: the zero-based index of the target column.

So the method `getString()` parameter index starts at 0. You are requesting the parameter with index 1 which is the second column.

```
return cursor.getString(1);
```

Since you are requesting only one column in your SELECT statement, and you are trying to get the second one, there is an exception and this is why it's failing.

To fix it change the previous line by this one:

```
return cursor.getString(0);
```

Comment: i thought this index is in relation with total number of rows in table, not only select statement, that solved my problem , thanks . 
i will accept this answer